# System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid when inserting a record in LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, exception

On my development machine everything is working fine, however as soon as I publish it to the server I get

System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

This is happening on

```
db.SubmitChanges();
```

I've check out https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=351358  and it still causes me errors

I also ran the Windows Update and everything is up to date on the server

Comment: Is your Development SQL Server the same version as your Production SQL Server (i.e. Both 2005 or both 2008, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have resolved the issue.

What appears to be the problem is that I have tables that have Id as Int and the Primary keys and also have GUID's as a fields which is defined as Unique, and the Guid field is a key to another table and being used as a foreign key.

When I set the Guid field as the primary key in the table the problem goes away.

I've not created a test project to prove this, due to time constraints as we are going live next week

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what you're trying to submit to the database, so anything I suggest will be (educated) guesswork. However, the thing that springs to mind is to check is the date format on your machine vs the server. <strike>This could be at the OS level or the database level.</strike>

If your machine is UK and the server is US then if you had a string representing the date in UK format (e.g. 30/9/2009) it would fail as there aren't 30 months.

However, as you say it's not this specific problem, look for differences between your development environment and the server to highlight what could be the problem areas.

An incomplete list of things to check:

- different operating systems. I'm assuming you're on XP/Vista and the Server is on Windows Server. Get a machine with the same OS and debug it there. Is your development machine 32 bit and the server 64 bit (or vice versa)?
- different versions of the .NET runtime. Make sure that the server is running the same version as your development machine.
- other libraries etc. Is there something installed on your development machine you've not installed on the server?

Comment: No date fields in the table

It is happening all over the place not just on one submit, most of the tables it is failing to insert, the only ones it is not are very simple tables

Comment: @Coppermill - in that case look for the differences between the environments.

Comment: Okay I've been performing some tests

Both environments are 32 bit
I've copied all the development files to the server and pointed the connectionstring to the server db 
I am running .Net 3.5 sp1 on both server and development.
All reference files are held in the bin directory and are the same as on my development box
I have connected from the Dev box to the live SQL db and that works okay.

I'm a little at a loss as to what to do next

Comment: I've had this application working without any problems just two weeks ago, and the changes I have made are not major and nothing new has been added either.

This is why I am so confused.

Comment: @Coppermill - I can't think of anything else at the moment, sorry.

Comment: I have created a number of Unit Tests using nunit, testing both the models and the controllers and they work on development and the server.

What other tests can I do to replicate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the data type of any column in the model, or in the database? That exception is usually thrown as a result of a mismatch between the data type used in the L2S model and the data type used in the database.

Alternatively, do you have any varchar(1) or nvarchar(1) fields? If so, the L2S designer will by default map those to System.Char. This is an incorrect mapping since a varchar(1) or nvarchar(1) can contain an empty string while a System.Char must contain exactly one character, and can result in InvalidCastExceptions being thrown (although that mismatch usually occur when retrieving data, not when submitting)...

Comment: Database's are the same, SQL 2008

Comment: Ok. Is the problem easy to reproduce? If so, write a code snippet that reproduces it on the server. Then update that code snippet to do a GetChangeSet right before SubmitChanges. Serialize the change set and inspect the data to see if there is something 'funny' going on. Also, if you can include the SQL-DDL for creating one of the affected tables as well as the DBML and/or class definition from the [dbmlfile].designer.cs for the same table in your question then that might shed some light on what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

I face the same exception when calling:

```
DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

after altering an object on the context. and same it worked in development machine and in the server, i got same cast error.

I had an association between two tables using a string property as the key.

To fix, I removed the association.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I had changed into my local database, and forgot to make this changes to my  production database.